# Como tratar campos Null no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query, null

Ola, preciso saber qual a melhor forma de utilizar o COALESCE para tratar os campos nulos da minha tabela.
Meu proble é o seguinte, estou simulando 6 Lojas e seus respectivos cartoes, vamos supor que uma ou mais lojas nao vendeu produto no cartao Amex, quando executo minha query ele me retorna 'null'. E eu precisava substituir por zero. 
Com o COALESCE isso é possivel?
Segue foto : [image: Exemplo do problema "null"]

Imagem da query: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acredito que já foi respondida, mas em uma proxima pergunta, não utilize imagens para mostrar o código, coloque como texto formatado mesmo. Imagens você pode usar para mostrar o resultado, ou uma tela por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `coalesce` é uma função que retorna o valor do primeiro parâmetro se ele não for nulo. Se for nulo retorna o valor informado no segundo parâmetro, conforme documentação [1].

No caso da query informada será preciso primeiro modificar os campos realizando uma conversão explícita para `numeric` e informando no segundo parâmetro `0` quando não houver valor correspondente a bandeira.

```
coalesce(cast(vb.bandeiras->>'AMEX' as numeric), 0) as amex
```

Segue query completa abaixo. Criei uma nova coluna `ELO` que não possui registros nas tabelas para simular o tratamento dos valores nulos.

```
with vendas as(
    select 
        t.nome as store_nome,
        c.nome as card_nome,
        sum(s.valor) as total_sale
    from sale s 
        inner join store t 
            on (t.id = s.store_id_fk)
        inner join credit_card c 
            on (c.id = s.credit_card_fk)
    where 
        data between '2017-01-01' and '2017-01-31' 
    group by 
        t.nome,
        c.nome 
), vendas_por_loja as (
    select
        store_nome,
        sum(total_sale) as total
    from vendas
    group by store_nome
), vendas_por_bandeira as (
    select 
        store_nome,
        jsonb_object_agg(card_nome,total_sale) as bandeiras
    from
        vendas
    group by store_nome
)
select 
    vb.store_nome,
    coalesce(cast(vb.bandeiras->>'AMEX' as numeric), 0) as amex,
    coalesce(cast(vb.bandeiras->>'VISA'  as numeric), 0)as visa,
    coalesce(cast(vb.bandeiras->>'DINERS'  as numeric), 0)as diners,
    coalesce(cast(vb.bandeiras->>'MASTER' as numeric), 0) as master,
    coalesce(cast(vb.bandeiras->>'ELO' as numeric), 0) as elo,
    vl.total
from vendas_por_bandeira vb
    inner join vendas_por_loja vl
        on (vb.store_nome=vl.store_nome);

store_nome | amex | visa | diners | master | elo | total 
------------+------+------+--------+--------+-----+-------
Loja 02    |   60 |   60 |     60 |     60 |   0 |   240
Loja 01    |  150 |  100 |     80 |     50 |   0 |   380
(2 registros)
```

[1] https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL